# Property method in python

Tags: python

Can someone explain me this behavior as to why 1) doesn't work while 2) and 3) works

1)

```
class bm(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.a=val
    def get(self):
        return self.a
    def set(self,val):
        self.a=val
        a=property(get,set)


In [43]: ob1=bm('vin')
```

gives me Recursive error
,while the below code works fine

2)

```
class bm(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self._a=val
    def get(self):
        return self._a
    def set(self,val):
        self._a=val
        a=property(get,set)


In [43]: ob1=bm('vin')
```

Works fine.I can access ob.a and do ob.a=''

Even this works fine

3)

```
class bm(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.a=val
    def get(self):
        return self._a
    def set(self,val):
        self._a=val
        a=property(get,set)

In [43]: ob1=bm('vin')
```

Works fine.I can access ob.a and do ob.a=''

Comment: Getters and setters in python are unnecessary.  You can just directly access ob.a, so no need to define your get and set methods.

Comment: example 1) seems to cause recursion..

Comment: "gives me error"? What error?

Comment: @Levon:Thanks for informing about the formatting,would do that in future.

Comment: Don't know who downvoted this question but for a Python newcomer the fact that "variables" and "methods" all live in the same namespace is not necessarily obvious.

Answer (score 5):

In the first example, you're creating the property `a`, which lets you do things like:

```
self.a               # Get the value
self.a = some_obj    # Set the value
```

But within the `a` property, you're referring to the `a` property *again*, via `self.a`! This will create a problem with recursion.

In the next examples, the property `a` is backed by the variable `self._a`, avoiding this recursion issue.

Comment: :Thanks..But self._a and self.a are different right?how does it work in example 3

Comment: @ftw: You're only calling `self.a` in the `__init__` method in the third example, not in the property methods.

Comment: But if i say ob.a="some val",it should set the value of ob.a,but as per set method ,it gives the impression as if it set value of ob._a.

Comment: @ftw: `obj.a` is essentially calling a method (even though you don't use parentheses). `obj.a = some_val` is basically just `obj.set(some_val)`, and `obj.a` is basically just `obj.get()`.

Comment: Got that part,but wat confuse me is,if i have a code like this:   class dm(object):
   ....:     def __init__(self,val):
   ....:         self.a=val
   ....:     def set(self,val):
   ....:         self._a=val
           ob=am('vin')
           ob.a---->vin
            ob.set('she')
            ob.a--->'vin' 
       I understand,the above behaviour,but the property method also should have behaved the same way for example 3 know?

Answer (score 3):

The point here is that in Python, everything (including functions, methods, "properties" - or any other descriptor - classes and even modules) is an object, and that there's no distinct namespaces for "data" and "functions or methods". IOW, in Python, an object has attributes, period  - no "member data" nor "member functions". Even the base classes are attributes (and are themselves objects so they have attributes too).

The attribute lookup rules are (quite simplified - I won't mention some special cases like slots etc):

for reading:

1. first look for an attribute by that name in the parent classes. If
   found AND this attribute implements the "get" part of the descriptor protocol, call
   that attribute's `__get__` method.
2. then look for an instance attribute in the instance's `__dict__`
3. then if the class (or one of the parent classes) has a `__getattr__` method, call it
4. then raise an AttributeError exception

for setting:

1. first look for an attribute by that name in the parent classes. If
   found AND this attribute implements the "set" part of the descriptor protocol, call
   that attribute's `__set__` method.
2. then store the attribute in the instance's `__dict__`

I mentionned but did not explain the descriptor protocol. This protocol (if you come from Java, a protocol is kind of an "implied" interface - you don't have to declare it, just to implement it) says that if an object has a `__get__` method and eventually a `__set__` method (here again I overly simplify by not mentionning the `__del__` part) AND is a class attribute then when looked up on an instance of the class it's `__get__` method will be called (with the instance and class as arguments) on "read" lookup and it's `__set__` method will be called (with the instance and value) on "write".

IOW, the descriptor protocol is the basis for computed attributes in Python.

Now about the `property` type (yes,it is a class, not a function): it does implement the descriptor protocol, in a very simple way. Here's a simplified version of how the property type would be implemented in pure Python (not taking the `__del__` part into account):

```
class property(object):
    def __init__(self, fget, fset=None, doc=None):
        self.fget = fget
        self.fset = fset
        self.doc = doc

   def __get__(self, instance, cls=None):
       if not instance:
           return self
       return self.fget(instance)

  def __set__(self, instance, value):
      if not self.fset:
          raise AttributeError("attribute is read-only")
      self.fset(instance, value)
```

Back to the question - given the class statement :

```
class Something(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.a=val
    def get(self):
        return self.a
    def set(self,val):
        self.a=val
    a=property(get,set)
```

We have a class object `Something` with a (class) attribute `a` which is a property with `fget=Something.get` and `fset=Something.set`. Now what happens when we instanciate `Something` ? The initializer is called with a `val` argument, and try to bind `self.a` to that argument. The attribute lookup rule (for "writing" - we should really say 'binding') kicks in and notice that the `Something` class object has an attribute `a` which - as an instance of the `property` type - implements the `__set__` part of the protocol descriptor. So the lookup rule calls `Something.a.__set__(theinstance, val)`, which resolves to `Something.a.fset(theinstance, val)`, which is implemented as `self.a = val`. New attribute lookup, finds a class attribute `a` implementing the binding part of the descriptor protocol, invoke it, etc..., bang, infinite recursion.

To make a long story short:  an attribute is an attribute is an attribute ;)

Note that in your third example, the `set` method try to set `self._a` and not `self.a`. Since the class has no descriptor named `_a`, this just create an instance attribute by that name, so no recursion here.

For more on the descriptor protocol, cf 
 - http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors
 - http://wiki.python.org/moin/ComputedAttributesUsingPropertyObjects

and if you want to understand what Python "methods" really are (hint: the `function` type implement the descriptor protocol) and why the 'self' argument is required, you can read this too: 
 - http://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod